# Most efficient way to test whether each element from one array exists in a another array, using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know the most efficient way of determining whether elements from a 1-d numpy array exist in another array.

Specifically, I have two numpy 1-d arrays. The first is an unsorted array of integers. The second is a sorted array of target values.

Sample input:

```
[45982, 124, 12, 1092, 45982, 1, 985, 299, 10092] # array 1

[1, 12, 299] # array 2
```

Expected output (i.e. array 1 elements in array 2):

```
[False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, False]
```

The actual arrays will be much longer: array 1 is likely to contain >5,000,000 elements, array 2 is likely to contain from 500,000 to 1,000,000 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> xs = np.array([45982, 124, 12, 1092, 45982, 1, 985, 299, 10092])
>>> ys = np.array([1, 12, 299])
>>> np.in1d(xs, ys)
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```